# Generate random certificates

Tags: java

I am looking for a utility class that can generate random certificate strings for testing purposes. Any idea if there is one already implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in Java X500 libraries are geared more towards *using* certificates than *generating* and *parsing* certificates.  You might find a way to do what you want, but it would almost certainly be messy and in a protected API (`sun.security.*`).

I suggest you include the Bouncy Castle library (Apache License).  It has a class called `X509V3CertificateGenerator` that you can use to set the fields of a certificate (issuer, subject, expiry date, etc).

You should then be able to get the PEM string from it using the `PEMWriter` class.

Comment: Note that `X509V3CertificateGenerator` has been deprecated (at least in Bouncy Castle 1.47). They suggest to use `X509v3CertificateBuilder` (not in the `bcprov` but in the `bcpkix` jar) instead.

Comment: Now it's in the `bcmail` jar

Comment: @KeksArmee: it's still in `bcpkix`.

Answer (score 7):

To add to solution given by martijno,

Instead of writing your own content signer, JCAContentSigner can be used to avoid mappings to AlgorithmIdentifier (i.e. OID).

JcaContentSignerBuilder takes algorithm names as defined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Signature).

```
X509v3CertificateBuilder certBuilder = new X509v3CertificateBuilder(issuer, serialNumber, startDate, expiryDate, subject, SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded()));
JcaContentSignerBuilder builder = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withRSA");
ContentSigner signer = builder.build(keyPair.getPrivate());

byte[] certBytes = certBuilder.build(signer).getEncoded();
CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)certificateFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(certBytes));
```

Comment: Am i right if this isn't a self signed cert i just replace the private key with the private key of the CA?